# Add Web Reference option missing in VS2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, console-application

I'm trying to add a Web Reference to a VS2008 .Net 3.5 Console Application but the option's not there. The options to "Add Reference" and "Add Service Reference" are there.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Kirk Evans blogged about that very issue [Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/kaevans/archive/2008/03/18/where-the-heck-is-add-web-reference-in-visual-studio-2008.aspx)

Basically, you just add a service reference.  A web reference is just one type of service you can add.

Answer (score 30):

1. Right click References and click 'Add Service Reference'
2. In the Add Service Reference dialog click Advanced
3. In the Advanced Dialog click 'Add Web Reference'
4. Continue as you normally would for an asmx web service.

Answer (score 3):

A Service Reference is the same as a Web Reference -- that is, you can add an ASMX web service as a reference and it will generate your proxies/etc. just like Add Web Reference did.

The change is to support WCF and have all remote ("service") references look and act the same in VS.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to pass the url to the asmx, not the wsdl